# FFMpeg : how to blur two fixed regions at the bottom of the video file?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to blur to rectangular regions at the bottom of the video. Only short region around center should stay as it is, and 140 pixels regions on both sides should be blurred.
The left region is ok, but just cannot set correctly the right one. For visual reason, I'm displaying it higher, but I just cannot get x coordinate and size in correct position.

```
ffmpeg -i Test1.mp4 -filter_complex  \
"[0:v]crop=iw/2-40:140:0:ih-140,avgblur=10[b0]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2-50:140:iw/2+200:ih-140,avgblur=5[b1]; \
 [0:v][b0]overlay=0:H-h[ovr0]; \
 [ovr0][b1]overlay=W/2+100:H-h-500" \
 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart Test_blur.mp4
```

As FFMpeg newbie, I must be doing something obviously wrong.
Thanks in advance,
regards.

Answer (score 0):

So, your 2nd crop args are `iw/2-50:140:iw/2+200:ih-140`

For width, you are telling the filter to take a horizontal portion equal to 50px less than half-width, starting at 200 pixels to the right of half-width. That's not possible. So, ffmpeg will adjust x so it can extract the requested width, so adjusted x is `iw/2+50`. Use that in overlay.